# How to have email links open in a new IE window

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer, outlook-express, email-client

When I click a link in an email, IE(7) opens up at that address. When I click another email link it opens the second link over the first one, re-using the same window. How to get it to leave the first open page alone and instead to open further links in either new windows or tabs?

The email client is Outlook Express v6.

I've already got IE set to not reuse windows for launching shortcuts.

Comment: What email client are you using?

Comment: Outlook Express

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using Google Chrome instead of IE.

Answer (score 1):

Some clients you can hold the ctrl or shift key down when you click a link to open it in a new tab or window.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work with OE.